# What do $f, \t", "\n" mean when linearizing fasta using the awk?

Tags: shell, awk, syntax

I am trying to linearize fasta using awk. I am totally new to it. I have a script

```
awk '/^>/ {printf("%s%s\t",(N>0?"\n":""),$0);N++;next;} {printf("%s",$0);} END {printf("\n");}'  < $f | tr "\t" "\n" > ${f/.fasta/_lin.fasta}
```

I dont understand anything in the `< $f | tr "\t" "\n" > ${f/.fasta/_lin.fasta}`. What is `$f`, whats `tr`, `t`, `n`. Where exactly I am supposed to give the input file? Can someone please elaborate?

Comment: `f` is a variable presumed to contain the name of the input file. The rest of your question is basically asking for a tutorial on how to use the shell and the `tr` command, which is far too broad for a single Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's step through that code piece by piece. First, I'll add some white space to make it more legible:

```bash
awk '
  /^>/ {
    printf("%s%s\t", (N>0?"\n":""), $0);
    N++;
    next;
  }
  {
    printf("%s",$0);
  }
  END {
    printf("\n");
  }
' < $f \
  | tr "\t" "\n" \
  > ${f/.fasta/_lin.fasta}
```

Okay. First, `$f` is your input file. The code's author expects it to contain `.fasta`, presumably at the end, like `myfile.fasta`. The `<` operator in shell scripts is redundant in this particular case (unless you have an equals sign in the filename since `awk` may interpret that as a variable assignment), simply telling `awk` to consume the contents of that file.

AWK then comes in and matches lines that start with `>`. On those lines, it will print a newline (if N > 0) or else nothing, followed by the contents of the line. It then increments N and skips the next command for that line. Other lines are printed as they're seen. After reading all of the lines of `$f`, a final newline is printed.

This `awk` code is not very legible. It could be rewritten like this:

```bash
awk '
  /^>/ && N++ {
    printf "\n";
  }
  {
    print;
  }
  END {
    printf "\n";
  }
'
```

The only tricky piece here is that `N` is initially zero, so when you say `N++` the first time, it returns the value before incrementing (zero = false) and therefore that condition does not trigger. When you say it the second time, it returns the value before the next incrementing (one = true) and therefore that condition triggers. Anything that is not an empty string or a zero evaluates as true.

On one line, and more golfed, that could be `awk '/^>/&&N++{printf"\n"}1;END{printf"\n"}'` (`1;` triggers the default action, which is to print the line).

After `awk`, the output is passed to `tr` to translate all tabs (`\t`) into newlines (`\n`). Then the output is piped using the `>` operator to write to a file described by the shell replacement `${f/.fasta/_lin.fasta}`, which replaces the first instance of `.fasta` in `$f` with `_lin.fasta`, so our example input file `myfile.fasta` is transformed to output file `myfile_lin.fasta`.

Comment: Thank you very very much Adam. Exactly what I needed to know.

Answer (score 0):

> Where exactly I am supposed to give the input file?

You should probably get and comprehend *User Manual* for tool **before** attemping to use it, unless you declared earlier potential damage as acceptable.

```
tr "\t" "\n"
```

This is `tr` command with 2 arguments, most linux commands are furnished with manual which you can access like so

```
man tr
```

popular one have also online versions, for example [`tr` manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tr) from where meaning of `\t` and `\n` might be found

```
\n
    new line
\t
    horizontal tab
```

Comment: Did not know how to access the manual. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing OP is trying to do something like this combining both the `awk` and `tr` commands :

```
 1  test
 2  123
 3  >456
 4  mnq
 5  >yesthis
 6  nothis
 7  789
```

> ```
> {m,g}awk '{ 
>        printf("%.*s%s%.*s",
>              (!__<+(___ +=_= !__ <  NF))*_,
>               RS, $+__, _*(_ !=___),RS)
> } END { 
>        print RS }' FS='^>' ORS=
> ```

```
 1  test123>456mnq
 2  >yesthis
 3  nothis789
```

Comment: Yes, thats the end results. Multifasta are in the format like you mentioned and I wanted linearized fasta like the output.